# Default value for resultCode when activity finishes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

This might be a basic question, but I hoping to get some clarity.

What I am trying to do:
1) Starting an activity with a requestCode, and handling two operations in 
onActivityResult, one using RESULT_OK, another using RESULT_CANCELLED. 
I explicitly state each of them.

The issue is even when I close the activity just using back button and not setting any result the Activity in the back stack receives RESULT_CANCELLED.

Going through the source code I see that RESULT_CANCELLED is the default value for the resultcode and that the resultcode is always sent back.

[image]

[image]

Am i reading this right and is this what happens all the time? or am I doing something wrong in my application?

Source: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java

Comment: you have to call `setResult` in the activity to get a non-default value: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)

Answer (score 7):

When your starting Activity is restarting, the onActivityResult(..) method of this Activity is called before the onResume() method is called. check [Doc for Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))

And the default resultCode is RESULT_CANCELLED.

You must explicitly call setResult(int) in the started Activity to change the value of resultCode.

And that's why it's important to check resultCode == RESULT_OK in the onActivityResult method. **Because the onActivityResult can be called even if you have not called startActivityForResult.**

Which can be confusing, but that's the default behaviour.

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // so some work
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must always supply a result code by help of setResult() method

Comment: I agree that that is the method to be used. But there are instances where I do not need/want to set a result. In that case I observed that I I was getting REQUEST_CANCELLED for resultCode even though I I did not set it.

Comment: REQUEST_CANCELLED is the default option. If you start an activity with startActivityForResult() method, android expects you to return a result back to the calling activity.

Comment: If you cannot find any predefined result in startActivtyForResult() which is appropriate for your application then you can even create your own result codes, see the link for more details :-  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: In the above link go to the section "Starting Activities and Getting Results". You'll find the way to create your own result codes there.