# onActivityResult() is not working in fragment " OUTPUT: You haven't picked Image "

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

**This is my code and when i run the code then output will be "**you haven't picked images**"**

**sdk which i use currently in this app**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.letsget.humanitysavior"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the manifests permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

**Here is the fragment code**

```
public class NewPostPublicFragment extends Fragment {

    public NewPostPublicFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 3;
    String imageEncoded;
    List<String> imagesEncodedList;
    private GridView gvGallery;
    private NewPostImagesAdapter galleryAdapter;
    CarouselView carouselView;

    private ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_post_public, container, false);

        gvGallery = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ImageView selectimgicon = view.findViewById(R.id.selectimgicon);
        ImageView selectvideoicon = view.findViewById(R.id.selectvideoicon);
        ImageView selectcameraicon = view.findViewById(R.id.selectcameraicon);
        carouselView = view.findViewById(R.id.carouselview);
        final TextInputEditText postcategories = view.findViewById(R.id.postcategories);

        //carouselView.setPageCount(mThumbIds.length);
        //carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);

        //for image selection
        selectimgicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //LOGIC FOR PROFILE PICTURE
                selectImagesFromGallery();
            }
        });

        postcategories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final CharSequence[] items = { "Book", "Cloth", "Electronic", "Furniture", "Bag", "Social Post", "Other" };

                AlertDialog.Builder postCategoryBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext(),AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
                postCategoryBuilder.setTitle("Select Post Category");
                postCategoryBuilder.setIcon(R.mipmap.categoryicon);
                postCategoryBuilder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // the user clicked on colors[which]
                        postcategories.setText(items[which]);
                    }
                });
                postCategoryBuilder.show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    ImageListener imageListener = new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
            //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            imageView.setImageURI(mArrayUri.get(position));
        }
    };

    private void selectImagesFromGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try {

            Log.v(TAG, "requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode = "+ resultCode + ", data = " + data);
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                // Get the Image from data

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(data.getData()!=null){

                    Uri mImageUri = data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    mArrayUri.add(mImageUri);
                    galleryAdapter = new NewPostImagesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mArrayUri);
                    gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
                    gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);

                    carouselView.setPageCount(mArrayUri.size());
                    carouselView.setImageListener(imageListener);

                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);
                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                            cursor.close();

                            galleryAdapter = new NewPostImagesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),mArrayUri);
                            gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
                            gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
                            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
                                    .getLayoutParams();
                            mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);

                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this app and tap on image button then it open the gallery and select the images after that when i press the done button then it's not display images it just display toast message you haven't picked images

Comment: what is the output of the verbose log ?

Comment: requestCode=3,  resultCode = -1, data = image\*.....

Comment: this is log output which i use in onActivityResult method

Comment: it seems like everything is ok, try to remove the super.onActivityResult

Comment: Did you set the necessary permissions?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

this is permission which i ask user and aslo i was tried to resomve super.OnActivityResult method still not solved and i use sdk 28 min 21

Answer (score 1):

Check these Steps:

1. Give permission to use camera in `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Use this code to get image properly

   ```
     String RequestCode=123; 

     @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RequestCode && resultCode== RESULT.OK){
             //Here get your image code
        }

     }
   ```
3. Also Check `Toast` in your `OnActivityResult()` method and check `if` condition is true or false. Probably your `if` condition is false that's why image is not received from gallery.

Comment: codition is going false i don't know why because log.v dislplay the result this requestCode=3, resultCode = -1, data = image*..... according to log.v result this condition is being true but still it is false

Comment: do one more step.    set the value of result from where you are calling function startActivityForResult() with the help of setResult() method

Comment: also check and try according this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838890/default-value-for-resultcode-when-activity-finishes